# How to make the coordinate indicator in a plot bigger?

Tags: plotting

I want the little vertical line which indicate the coordinate of the system in plot bigger. For example, in the picture below I marked those lines I am talking about with a blue rectangle. How can I make all such a indicators bigger?

[image]

Comment: @YvesKlett It's not a duplicate because the link you quote doesn't cover framed plots.

Comment: @eldo `FrameTicks` was mentioned in comments, though. I think it can be considered a duplicate, but note that duplicates are not necessarily deleted since it can be better for there to be multiple ways to find an answer. On the other hand the two questions might be merged at a later date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example:

```
n=0.1;

Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Ticks -> {Table[{x, x, n}, {x, 1, 10}], {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

```
n = 0.05;

Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {Table[{x, x, n}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/2}], 
   Table[{x, x, n}, {x, -1, 1, 0.5}]}]
```

[image]